# How to set an array of current usernames

Tags: array, username

I am trying to get this code working so I can list a set of usernames that are not allowed to see updates in the Wordpress admin panel.  Right now it only works with a single username.  Is there a way to set this up as an array so that I can list multiple usernames?  Kind of something like:

```
 if($user && isset($user->user_login) && array('username', 'username2') == $user->user_login
```

Here is the current code that works for just one username:

```
function disable_wp_updates() {
    global $wp_version;
    return (object) array( 'last_checked' => time(), 'version_checked' => $wp_version, );
}
add_action('admin_init', 'check_wp_username');
function check_wp_username()
{
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if($user && isset($user->user_login) && 'username' == $user->user_login ) {
        // do stuff
        add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_core', 'disable_wp_updates' );     // Disable WordPress core updates
        add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_plugins', 'disable_wp_updates' );  // Disable WordPress plugin updates
        add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_themes', 'disable_wp_updates' );   // Disable WordPress theme updates
    // remove the update count number:
        global $menu,$submenu;
        $menu[65][0] = 'Plugins';   
        $submenu['index.php'][10][0] = 'Updates';   
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So right now you have this

```
if ($user && isset($user->user_login) && 'username' == $user->user_login ) {
```

To check for one specific user. If you want to check against multiple usernames, PHP's function [`in_array()`](https://php.net/in_array) comes in handy

```
$allowed = array(
    'user1',
    'user2',
);
if ($user && isset($user->user_login) && in_array($user->user_login, $allowed) ) {
```